# Saving programmatically added Views on orientation change?

Tags: android, view, orientation

I'm having trouble with saving Views on orientation change. So here's what's going on for me. I have a class extending HorizontalScrollView that creates a LinearLayout and a button in it's constructor. More buttons are added to the LinearLayout when a button is clicked. When the activity starts, I set the Action Bar to this custom view and it all works just fine, adding and deleting buttons from the LinearLayout. But, here's where the problem starts. If a switch orientation, onCreate is restarted, so a new instantiation of my custom view is created and set to the Action Bar. Therefore, my custom view returns to the beginning when I switch orientation.

How do I persist the view's hierarchy throughout orientation changes?

Answer (score 1):

When orientation changes activity is destroyed and recreated.

In your manifest add the following to your activity.

```
      <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      //Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation.
      //add screenSize for api 13 and above.
```

Now, when one of these configurations change, MyActivity does not restart. Instead, the MyActivity receives a call to onConfigurationChanged(). This method is passed a Configuration object that specifies the new device configuration.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Wouldn't doing it this way fall apart when I exit the application and after a while return to it? I would have to restore the last View state. This is simple going around it, and it poses another problem.

Comment: When you exit the application the activity are destroyed. So it will be recreated on launch. The above will prevent activity from being recreated during orientation change

Comment: This not recommended. You should handle orientation change yourself

Answer (score -1):

The best way for that much information is to add android:configChanges="orientation"  to your activity in the manifest, and it will prevent the destroy and relaunch functionality that Android assumes you want.  Truthfully I'd suggest adding that to any activity that doesn't have a different layout file for landscape and portrait mode.