# Programatically created views disappear after changing layout then changing it back

Tags: java, android

I have a class in my code that creates and adds an ImageView to a layout when created, as follows:

```
// This code is part of another class (BasicEnemySpawner) that takes a constraintLayout and all of these other factors as inputs
public BasicEnemy spawn(){
        BasicEnemy basicEnemy = new BasicEnemy(bHealth, yPos, (int) xPos, bDamage, aliveSpritesheet, deadSpritesheet, xVel, context, new ImageView(context));
        basicEnemy.updateImage();
        // constraintLayout is defined earlier.
        constraintLayout.addView(basicEnemy.thisImageView);
        return basicEnemy;
    }
```

This code, and all other code like it in my program, works completely fine the first time. In the onCreate method, I set a variable equal to findViewByID(R.id.constraintLayout), create a new spawner, and have it spawn some stuff.

After I change the view and change it back though (i.e.)

```
setContentView(R.layout.view2)
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
```

All of the views disappear. It seems as if they still exist, but they are not visible

I tried to do something like

```
mainLayout.removeView(basicEnemy)
mainLayout.addView(basicEnemy)
```

to refresh the views, but that also failed.

Comment: Every time your screen is refreshed the activity resets to the original state. That's why android uses ViewModel. If you need to keep the views u need to keep them as component inside a life-cycle aware code. Eg make a view array inside a  viewmodel and store them in it.

Comment: @SayokMajumder would I then run mainLayout.addView on each view in the array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858413/saving-programmatically-added-views-on-orientation-change  check this first if this solves the problem. Else check this page https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel